# Why when setting display to 1280x1024 it set's the display on 1920x1200?

Tags: display

I have been searching to how to add a resolution to display setting or just setting a higher resolution for display and i found the blow code at last :

```
 # gtf 1920 1200 60 -x
 # xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
 # xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1200_60.00
 # xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1200_60.00
```

and then i just Replaced my own parameters like :

```
# gtf 1280 1024 60 -x
# xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  193.16  1920 2048 2256 2592  1200 1201 1204 1242  -HSync +Vsync
# xrandr --addmode DVI-1 1280x1024_60.00
# xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
```

But the problem is that when i write the last line and press inter it adds 1920x1200 to display settings but in the moment when i write :

```
# xrandr -q
```

it shows me this :

```
DVI-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0 
800x600        60.3     56.2  
848x480        60.0  
640x480        59.9  
1280x1024_60.00   60.0*
```

As you see the display is set on 1280x1024 but its on 1920x1200 in display settings and on monitor.  :|
Does any one have any idea what should i do?

Comment: I know that i must change the other parameters as well in the second line but i don't know how to exactly change them that  i don't get any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the rest of parameters with the command:

```
cvt 1028 1024 60
```

Copy all the line starting with "Modeline" except this word.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't around for a while and you all answered so perfect and soon     ..... Thanks so much it helped for real.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is on the right track but has a fatal typo.  It should be

```
cvt 1280 1024 60
```

I couldn't edit the above answer to fix it because I wasn't changing enough characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a graphical tool to set the right parameters.

[This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx/) program sets your resolution using `randr` and keeps it even after reboot. I made it, so I know that it works :)